# Addition of array in python with list in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to sum up the below to list?

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I apply this code:

```
Total=[x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

So the output will be:

```
Total=[[1,1,2,2,3,3],[4,4,5,5,6,6],[7,7,8,8,9,9]]
```

but I wish to get

```
Total=[[2,4,6],[8,10,12],[14,16,18]]
```

Anyone can share me some ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close:

```
>>> [[x+y for x,y in zip(sub1, sub2)] for sub1, sub2 in zip(a,b)]
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14, 16, 18]]
```

You just have to realize that you need to iterate one level deeper, since the return value of `zip(a,b)` are *sublists*, and if you add sublists, you get concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged it with NumPy so I'll present the NumPy approach:

```
import numpy as np
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

np.array(a) + np.array(b)  # this will do element-wise addition
# array([[ 2,  4,  6],
#        [ 8, 10, 12],
#        [14, 16, 18]])
```

It's actually enough to convert only one to a NumPy array - but internally NumPy will convert the other one to a NumPy array nevertheless. It's just less to type:

```
np.array(a) + b
a * np.array(b)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)?

```
In [326]: import numpy as np

In [327]: np.add(a, b)
Out[327]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [14, 16, 18]])
```